# Where is the navigator panel in .net's visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm used to the Netbeans environment, now I'm learning C# in Visual Studio, I can't seem to figure out where the navigator is in the VS setting, in NB it shows me the members of a class, I believe it must exist in VS, can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the class view.  Look under the "View" menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for either the Solution Explorer or the Class view.  Both of which are located in the View menu.